# Symfony- docker container Could not open input file: bin/bash

Tags: php, docker, symfony, docker-compose, dockerfile

I started my **Symfony 6** project with `Docker` successfully.
I have a problem when accessing the **PHP** *container* and trying to run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations`.

The error:

> Could not open input file: bin/console

My steps:

```
docker ps //checked php container name
docker exec -it php_container_name /bin/bash //entered with success
```

Then I am in container like;

```
root@2a9a3e61c23b:/var/www/html#
```

And when entering the above command, the error above is shown.

Docker file:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libicu-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    wget

# Installing Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && composer --version

RUN apt-get -y install cron default-mysql-client
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql
```

and docker .yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
      - ".:/app:cached"

  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker-configs/php
    volumes:
      - "./docker-configs/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini"
      - ".:/app:cached"
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  postgresdata:
```

Comment: What does `ls -l` tell you right after you enter the container? Do you see the `bin` folder? Does it contain the `console` file? What are the owner/group/permissions of the directory/file if they exist? Please do not reply in comments, [edit](../edit) your question to add the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a new project with Symfony. They also shared the following address with Docker in their Symfony document:

https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker

Make sure you have installed the composer package:

```
composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle
```

and I had this same problem you mentioned. and the command `php bin/console` fixed the problem. I recommend you to review the docker files in the link above. I hope I could help.